# Adding multiple LIKE parameters yield no results

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add multiple 'LIKE' to my SQL list here but after the first 'LIKE', it stops returning results.

Code:

```
SELECT
T1.item_no,
T1.inv_id,
T2.on_hand_qty

FROM inventory_items T1
INNER JOIN inventory_quantities T2 ON T1.inv_id = T2.inv_id

WHERE item_no LIKE 'DP105%'
```

So say my list is this:

DP105A

DP105B

DP105C

DP108A

DP108B

As my code stands, it generates everything that starts with DP105 (good!)
But once i add `AND item_no LIKE 'DP108%'` it generates an empty list. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want "OR":

```
SELECT
T1.item_no,
T1.inv_id,
T2.on_hand_qty

FROM inventory_items T1
INNER JOIN inventory_quantities T2 ON T1.inv_id = T2.inv_id

WHERE item_no LIKE 'DP105%'
OR item_no LIKE 'DP108%'
```

`AND` would mean item_no begins with DP108 and DP105...but this is impossible. It can only begin with one of those strings.

Comment: god im so stupid. Thank you! Is there an easier way to type this out? Like if i have a list of 100 things, do i have to keep adding OR item_no LIKE over and over?